# How to inject C# dll to another process

Tags: c#, dll, hook, inject

Anybody know how/if I can create C# DLLs then inject them into another process (not .net) and execute my code, overriding existing methods?

Comment: Have you looked at <a href="http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/Reflexil-csharp-code-injection-in-assemblies.aspx">Reflexil</a>?

Comment: Are you talking about [Hooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) ? if so, you may want to read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/netwin32hooks.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting a CLR host into a running process - possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787343/injecting-a-clr-host-into-a-running-process-possible)

Comment: @Dinah, when doing links on SO, use the `[url](text)` syntax.

Comment: @Inuyasha: it used to be an answer below but it was converted to a comment (by a mod?) and now it's too old to edit.

Answer (score 1):

[easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)